# Nuxt change favicon by page

Tags: html, nuxt.js, favicon

I have certain cases where certain routes need a different favicon.
I've tried throwing this code in the head, and while this does work, it adds another favicon underneath the previous one, and does not overwrite it.

page.vue:

```
head () {
    return {
        title: 'my website title',
        link: [{
            rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: 'https://s.yimg.com/rz/l/favicon.ico'
        }]
    }
}
```

```
<link data-n-head="ssr" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link data-n-head="ssr" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://s.yimg.com/rz/l/favicon.ico">
```

How do you go about overwriting a favicon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a `hid` to the favicon in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
link: [{
    hid: 'icon',
    rel: 'icon',
    type: 'image/x-icon',
    href: 'link-to-fallback-favicon.png'
}]
```

You can now overwrite it in the pages `head` method by using the same hid:

```js
head()
    return {
        link: [{
        hid: 'icon',
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/x-icon',
        href: 'link-to-new-favicon.png'
}]
```

Nuxt will automatically overwrite once you navigate to that page, and use the general once from nuxt.config.js when you navigate away.

Comment: Ah maybe the hid is what I was missing, I'll give it a shot thanks!

Answer (score -4):

I think this link can help you

https://reactgo.com/nuxt-change-favicon/

1. Open the nuxt app in your favorite code editor.
2. Navigate to the static folder and delete the favicon.ico file.
3. Now, add a new favicon inside the static folder.
4. Reload your nuxt app to see the new favicon.

Comment: That will change the favicon across the whole site. I wanted to change it dynamically on a page by page basis.